# componentWillReceiveProps do not fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following Higher Order Component to create a loading on my components:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Spinner from 'components/spinner';

const WithSpinner = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class SpinnerWrapper extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      console.log('Current props: ', this.props);
      console.log('Next props: ', nextProps);
    }

    render (){
      const { loading } = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
        {loading ?
          <Spinner />
          :
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</WrappedComponent>}
        </div>)
    }
  }

  SpinnerWrapper.propTypes = {
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  SpinnerWrapper.defaultProps = {
    loading: true,
  };

  return SpinnerWrapper;
};

export default WithSpinner;
```

and I have the following component who is wrapping in WithSpinner

```
const updateChartSeries = answersSummary => ({
  chartSeries: TasksTransforms.fromAnswerSummaryToClickEffectivenessChart(answersSummary),
  transposed: false,
  viewOptions: { type: 'pie', stacked: false, column: false },
});

class ClickEffectivenessChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartSeries: [],
      viewOptions: {
        type: 'pie',
        stacked: false,
        column: false,
      },
      title: 'Click Effectiveness',
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ answersSummary }) {
    this.setState(updateChartSeries(answersSummary));
  }

  handleChartType = (type = 'pie') => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'pie':
        this.setState({ viewOptions: { type: 'pie', stacked: false, column: false } });
        break;
      case 'bar':
        this.setState({ viewOptions: { type: 'bar', stacked: false, column: false } });
        break;
      case 'column':
        this.setState({ viewOptions: { type: 'bar', stacked: false, column: true } });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  optionsDropdown = () => {
    const options = [
      { onClick: () => this.handleChartType('pie'), text: 'Pie' },
      { onClick: () => this.handleChartType('bar'), text: 'Bar' },
      { onClick: () => this.handleChartType('column'), text: 'Column' },
    ];

    return options;
  }

  render() {
    const { chartSeries, viewOptions, title } = this.state;

    return (
      chartSeries.length > 0 &&
      <div className="content" >
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <div className="box">
          <EffectivenessChart type={viewOptions.type} series={chartSeries} title={title} optionMenu={this.optionsDropdown()} stacked={viewOptions.stacked} column={viewOptions.column} transposed />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ClickEffectivenessChart.propTypes = {
  answersSummary: PropTypes.object, //eslint-disable-line
};

ClickEffectivenessChart.defaultProps = {
  answersSummary: {},
};

export default WithSpinner(ClickEffectivenessChart);
```

And sometimes the componentWillReceiveProps it no trigger and I can see why. I'm assuming that my WithSpinner controller have a problem but I can see what is the problem. The same behavior happen in all components wrapped with the WithSpinner controller

Any help please?

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Heatmap from 'components/heatmap';
import ClickEffectivenessChart from './click_effectiveness_chart';
import ClickEffectivenessTable from './click_effectiveness_table';
import AreaChart from './area_chart';
import SctHeatmap from './sct_heatmap';


class SctAnswersSummary extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.questionId) { this.fetchData(); }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.questionId !== this.props.questionId) { this.fetchData(); }
  }

  fetchData = () => { 
    const {
      datacenterId, accountId, projectId, questionId,
    } = this.props;
    this.props.actions.questionFetchRequest(datacenterId, accountId, projectId, questionId);
    this.props.actions.answersSummaryFetchRequest(datacenterId, accountId, projectId, questionId);
    this.props.actions.answersSctClicksFetchRequest(datacenterId, accountId, projectId, questionId);
  }

  render() {
    const { imageUrl, clicks, questionId, imageWidth, imageHeight } = this.props.answerSctClicks;
    const { answersSummaryLoading, answersSctLoading, answersSummary } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="content">
        <div className="content" >
          <SctHeatmap imageUrl={imageUrl} clicks={clicks} questionId={questionId} imageWidth={imageWidth} imageHeight={imageHeight} loading={answersSctLoading} />
          <br />
          <ClickEffectivenessChart answersSummary={answersSummary} loading={answersSummaryLoading} />
          <br />
          <AreaChart answersSummary={answersSummary} loading={answersSummaryLoading} />
          <br />
          <ClickEffectivenessTable answersSummary={answersSummary} loading={answersSummaryLoading} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SctAnswersSummary.propTypes = {
  datacenterId: PropTypes.string,
  accountId: PropTypes.string,
  projectId: PropTypes.string,
  questionId: PropTypes.string,
  questionSct: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types
  actions: PropTypes.shape({
    questionSctFetchRequest: PropTypes.func,
  }).isRequired,
  answersSummaryLoading: PropTypes.bool,
  answersSctLoading: PropTypes.bool,
};

SctAnswersSummary.defaultProps = {
  datacenterId: null,
  accountId: null,
  projectId: null,
  questionId: null,
  questionSct: {},
  answersSummaryLoading: true,
  answersSctLoading: true,
};

export default SctAnswersSummary;
```

Comment: ComponentWillReceiveProps doesn't fire on mount, only when props change. You may need to also use ComponentWillMount or ComponentDidMount

Answer (score 1):

It's because your HOC is a function stateless component, meaning that it doesn't have any lifecycle events. You need to convert `WithSpinner` to a class component and then the lifecycle events should flow through to your wrapped component:

```
const WithSpinner = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class extends React.Component {
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            console.log('Current props: ', this.props);
            console.log('Next props: ', nextProps);
        }
        render() {
            return <div>
                {this.props.loading ? 
                    <Spinner /> 
                : 
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </WrappedComponent>}
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, it's a good practice to make it more generic so curry `{props.children}` - return `<WrappedComponent {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</WrappedComponent>`

Comment: Thanks, but still have the same problem sometimes it fire the componentWillReceiveProps, sometimes no. I also check if the component is render onces, and is render only one time

Comment: Other question, it's really necessary the console.log inside the componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: No, the console.logs were just there as an example. You don't need to include `componentWillReceiveProps` at all as long as it's a class component. Are you sure you are passing updated props to `ClickEffectivenessChart`? Seeing it only render once makes me assume that it is never getting new props passed to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. here are the console.log using your example, Current props:  {answersSummary: List, loading: true}
Next props:  {answersSummary: {…}, loading: false}, as you can see they are changing, so I don't know why sometimes work and sometimes no

Comment: Can you post the code for where `<ClickEffectivenessChart />` gets used?

Comment: Done! just add the code where I use the ClickEffectivenessChart